# Forward discretization of the BSDE in the Deep BSDE method

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

In the Deep BSDE method proposed by E et al., (2017) and Han et al., (2018), the backward stochastic differential equation (BSDE):

$\begin{cases}
    dY_t &= -f(t, \mathbf{X}_t, Y_t, \mathbf{Z}_t)\ dt + \mathbf{Z}_t^\intercal \ d\mathbf{W}_t,\hspace{0.64cm} t\in[0, T]    \\
    Y_T &= g(\mathbf{X}_T)
    \end{cases}$

is discretized in a forward manner:

$\begin{cases}
    Y_t = Y_0 - \displaystyle\int_0^t f(s, \mathbf{X}_s, Y_s, \mathbf{Z}_s) ds + \displaystyle\int_0^t \mathbf{Z}_s^\intercal d\mathbf{W}_s, \ t \in [0, T]  \\
    Y_T = g(\mathbf{X}_T),
\end{cases}$

$Y_{t_{n+1}} \approx Y_{t_n} - f \bigl(
        t_n, \mathbf{X}_{t_n}, Y_{t_n}, \mathbf{Z}_{t_n})
    \bigr) \Delta t_n + \mathbf{Z}^\intercal_{t_n} \Delta \mathbf{W}_n,\hspace{0.5cm} Y_T = g(\mathbf{X}_T).$

Subsequently, the solution of the BSDE is approximated using a deep neural network.

My question is does this forward discretization change the "backward" nature of BSDE? I ask this because my lecturer in the field of analysis questioned how a BSDE can be solved in a forward manner despite its name suggesting otherwise.

E, W., Han, J., & Jentzen, A. (2017). Deep learning-based numerical
methods for high-dimensional parabolic partial differential equations
and backward stochastic differential equations. *Communications in
mathematics and statistics, 5* (4), 349–380.

Han, J., Jentzen, A. and E, W., 2018. Solving high-dimensional partial differential equations using deep learning. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 115*(34), pp.8505-8510.